# How to configure Telerik controls in a secure way for Sitecore?

Tags: security, best-practices

I'm tuning my Sitecore setup: review configs and settings, analyse use of external services and assess security gaps. And found that Telerik controls are enabled on CD instances but not sure how they are used in front-end.

How should I align Telerik controls setup on CM and CD servers with Sitecore recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore uses some Telerik UI controls for content management in WYSIWYG editor, spell checks and resources. These controls are only used on a Content Management instance and therefore make sure that you disable those controls on CD instances for security reasons.

As per [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/secure-the-telerik-controls.html) use proper Telerik encryption keys defined in application settings. It is up to you how you wish to control those keys, if you are in PaaS then I would recommend to take advantage of Azure app settings to manage them via Azure Portal instead of updating a `web.config` file. So to sum up my recommended approach is

- Telerik Controls settings are removed from the `<handlers>` section in
  `web.config` on CD and kept only on CM
- Telerik Controls keys are specified in Azure App settings area with
  some values different to “YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE“ that set by
  default